# Max/Min decomposition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

Imagine I have the following piecewise function:
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      6 & x\leq 8.5 \\
      14.5-x & 8.5< x < 10.5 \\
      4 & 10.5\leq x 
\end{cases}
$$
This could be rewritten as the following
$$
f(x) = \text{min}(6, \text{max}(4, 14.5-x))
$$
which can can be decomposed as
$$
f(x)=\text{max}(0, 10.5-x)-\text{max}(0, 8.5-x)+4
$$
or
$$
f(x)=\text{max}(0,x- 10.5)-\text{max}(0, x- 8.5)+6
$$
and I'm sure this could be also expressed using $\text{min}()$. My question then, is there a general rule to decompose nested max and mins in a linear combination of "simple" max and mins?

EDIT: by "simple" I mean with no nested max/min and ideally with $0$ as one of the two arguments

Comment: Well, addition distributes over $\max$ and $\min$, so $\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\max\{f(x)-g(x),0\}+g(x)$; you can always make one of the arguments $0$.

Comment: What are the allowed "pieces" of your functions? Linear? Polynomial? Analytic? Can you think of any way to decompose $$\begin{cases}0,\quad x\leq0\\\sin^2(x),\quad x\geq0\end{cases}$$ $$=\min\{\max\{0,x\},\sin^2(x)\}$$ for example?